# Javascript : store an image in the browser, then use it in markdown

Tags: javascript, image, typescript, markdown

I'm implementing a markdown editor and it accepts images with the syntax

```
![any text](http url)
```

Although I use this syntax because it is simpler in my case (but the syntax isn't really relevant, neither work)

```
![ID]
...
[ID]: url ("Image title")
```

It works well when I give an URL to the picture, but what I would do is **store the picture in the browser and display it**, then if the user posts his content, **the image should be uploaded**.

This seems like the best option to save space on the server, but I don't know if it's possible.

I've tried with a base64 image, but the URL is enormous and it makes the parser fail.

I'm open to any suggestions to deal with this issue, or if you know how to do what I want, feel free to explain to me !

So far, the Code I tested :

```js
fileChange(event: Event) {
  const files = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;

  if (!files || !files.length) { return; }

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const file = files.item(i);
    const fileType = file.name.split('.').slice(-1).toString();
    if (/* wrong extension */) { continue; }
    if (/* wrong size */) { continue; }
    this.createMediaUrl(file);
  }
}

createMediaUrl(file: File) {

  const media: { file: File, id: string, url: string, name: string } = {} as any;

  const FR = new FileReader();
  FR.onload = () => media.url = FR.result;
  FR.readAsDataURL(file);
  media.name = file.name;
  media.id = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-6);
  media.file = file;
  this.medias.push(media);
  console.log(media);
}
```

I should state that I work in **Typescript**, but it is a Javascript issue (at least to me).

I also **don't need help on any other thing** than this problem : the code I posted is a simplified code, all my checks are good and such. My only issue is with the markdown.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: If a `data:` URI doesn't work for you (and I'm not surprised), then I don't think you're going to have much choice but to put the image on the server and refer to it from there -- and delete it at some point if the user doesn't include it in the post eventually.

Comment: I'm using a backend as a service, and of course, every call and every bit of storage is to be paid ... That's why I'm asking for this. Is there a workaround that can be done ? I have access to the parsed string, maybe changing the source of the picture would work ?

Comment: You know, I bet you could store it in local storage (in Base64) and use a [service worker](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers-1/) to handle a fake URL locally...

Comment: **EDIT** didn't see your answer, thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of scenario is exactly why [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) was added to the specification. Base64-encoded strings can cause issues when they reach the size and/or memory limitations of various APIs, and so having access to a short, temporary, local URI string for a [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) can be handy, and as it happens, it's exactly what you need:

```
createMediaUrl(file: File) {
  const media: { file: File, id: string, url: string, name: string } = {} as any;

  media.url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  media.name = file.name;
  media.id = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-6);
  media.file = file;
  this.medias.push(media);
  console.log(media);
}
```

See [supporting browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls).

<sup>(Thanks to [@T.J.Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) for the link)</sup>

Comment: I'm using this method for videos right now, I'm a beginner when it comes to handling medias. If only I knew I could use it for images ... I will try that tomorrow, along with the service worker. Thank you for the Intel !

Comment: @trichetriche it works for any `blob` you pass to it, including constructed blobs, which is how I implemented [this nifty little demo](https://jsfiddle.net/patrob10114/o5r1adyz/show/) of [`synth-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/synth-js). (Shameless self-promoting)

Comment: @trichetriche: Probably no need to look into service workers for this purpose, as Patrick points out, this is what `createObjectURL` is for. Literally when you get a `File` object (drag-and-drop, file input, whatever), just pass it to `createObjectURL` and then you can use the resulting URL. If the user saves their post, you post the file and update the URLs in the text to match the saved URL.

Comment: Well then, I'll go for it and try it tomorrow. Thank you for your help !

Comment: I forgot to tell you (if you ever care), but it works like a charm. Thanks to that, I can even extend the parser to handle videos. Thank you a lot !